# Mysql not listed in phpinfo.php, only mysqlnd

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache

I have installed apache2, php54 and Mysql 5.6. I have enabled php to work with apache but mysql is not responsding. I have tried a mysql_connect() function in a sample file but I get this error:

```
 Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

I have added to mysql.sock on the mysql.default section of the php.ini file. I have searched all over the net for a solution but nothing. I have been told that there is a mysql.so file extension that should be enabled in the php.ini file but I dont know where to locate it.
I will appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqlnd` is the native MySQL driver for PHP. You should probably use the much improved [`mysqli` extension](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead of the deprecated `mysql` extension. These two both support and use `mysqlnd`.

Comment: Ok thanks but, my problem is, where do I find these extension files. What is their path directory within my installation.

Comment: what is your OS, is it Windows, Centos, Ubuntu or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows 7 - most posts on this subject point to uncommenting the extensions which I had already done.

In the end I changed the path to the extensions folder from a relative path:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

to absolute:

```
extension_dir = "c:\PHP\ext"
```

This worked for me - hope it helps someone googling for a solution.